# Error 1045 Access denied - Mac OSX 10.11.5 - no solutions found

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-elcapitan

As a software engineering student, I've been trying to connect to MySQL but it's driving me nuts with many solutions on Stack Overflow but none of them works. I have enabled my mac to have a root user to run as a system administrator but to no avail.

Despite correct passwords, I kept getting denied the access. I had success with workarounds on my PC but not on Mac. I cannot get to the deep root of the problem. My experience with terminal on Mac is extremely limit. I cannot find any information that will provide a good solution to overcome the error 1045 and it's my 3rd day with no success. To make matter worse, when I try to enter MySQL but I get 'command not found' but ./MySQL works.

Has anyone have had success in overcoming the problem with the workarounds?

EDIT: 
Forgot to add - due to error I am experiencing, there's no way I could reset the password in SQL statement. I've tried that but to no avail.

Comment: If you're getting access denied then either your username+password combination *is* incorrect, or you're not configuring it correctly. Remember `localhost` access and TCP access have different rules.

Comment: If it's the configuration issue, then I'm not sure how it is done. It's not the username/password issue. I already have those information. Could you point me to the correct link on configuration issue?

Comment: It turned out that I was using the wrong password the whole time!!! I finally made it through!